# MacOS : Cannot build project using Mono and msbuild

Tags: android, macos, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, mono

I'm trying to build Android project using the msbuild and Mono on the Mac.

Here is what I tried do:

**Installed mono for MacOSX**

**Installed msbuild tool from github repo (branch xplat)**

https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/wiki/Building-Testing-and-Debugging-on-.Net-Core-MSBuild

I executed command in the msbuild clonned dir

**Using a Mono MSBuild host: ./cibuild --host Mono**

After that dependecies was installed i tried to build the app using the following command:

```
msbuild BuildTypes/InstrumentMobileAndroid.proj /t:projectName_DeveloperBuild /p:Configuration=debug /p:Clean=no /p:Abi=armeabi-v7a /p:Parallelize=8 /m /fileLogger /flp:LogFile=AndroidBuild.log
```

**Which returns me following exception:**

```
"myWorkspace/myProject/myProject_II_/BuildTypes/InstrumentMobileAndroid.proj" (myProjectII_DeveloperBuild target) (1) ->
         myWorkspace/myProject/myProject_II_/BuildTypes/InstrumentMobile.targets(15,13): error MSB4226: The imported project "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.4.2/lib/mono/xbuild/ExtensionPack/4.0/MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks" was not found. Also, tried to find "ExtensionPack/4.0/MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks" in the fallback search path(s) for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) - "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/" . These search paths are defined in "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.4.2/lib/mono/msbuild/14.1/bin/MSBuild.exe.config". Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk in one of the search paths. [myWorkspace/myProject/myProject_II_/BuildTypes/InstrumentMobileAndroid.proj]
```

I tried to found any working solution for this (for example targeting to the .NetCore using  **./cibuild.sh --target CoreCLR**), but always with the same result.

I'm new using the msbuild on the Mac and i stucked on this.

How to do it in the right way please?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: You seem to be missing the `MSBuild extensions pack`. It is looking for this file - `ExtensionPack/4.0/MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks`. I am not sure how well the pack works on OSX.

Comment: Also, with recent Mono installations on OSX, you will find `msbuild` already installed. This version of msbuild will work well with Xamarin projects.